# Error 'declares a non-template function' in C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile

I compile a project with make command but this give me these errors:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -c Array.cc       
In file included from Array.cc:5:0:
Array.h:9:65: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream&    operator<<(std::ostream&, Array<Items>&)’ declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& fout, Array<Items>& ary);
                                                             ^
Array.h:9:65: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here) 
In file included from Array.cc:9:0:
List.h:28:64: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, List<Items>&)’ declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& fout, List<Items>& lst);   
                                                            ^
 Array.cc:112:5: error: specializing member ‘Array<int>::compare’ requires ‘template<>’ syntax
int Array<int>::compare(Array<int>* ar2)
 ^
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'Array.o' failed
make: *** [Array.o] Error 1
```

The code in Array.cc is

```
#include "Array.h"
```

The code in Array.h:9:65 is:

```
class Array{
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& fout, Array<Items>& ary);
  private:
  int theSz;
  int totSz;
  Items *theAry;
```

Can you explain to me these errors?  I use Ubuntu 15.10.  Maybe these are from deprecated function in C++, because this algorithm was developed in 2005.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What does Array.cc lines ~112 look like?

Comment: it contain this: int Array<int>::compare(Array<int>* ar2)

Comment: The `friend` issue is only a warning, but there is also an **error** on line 112, which you failed to provide the full code for. I vote for closing.

Comment: i think the problem is wel defined, i didn't add all the code, i add the errors and the ligns that generate the errors,also this is as porblem due to the c++ version, so i don't understand why you block my post, and why you think i don't respect the site chart, the proble was minima, complete...So i think you must upvote my post an give back my point :(

Answer (score 2):

If your `Array` class **is not meant to be a template**, your function should have the signature

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& fout, Array& ary);
```

Then you can loop over your `ary.theAry` within that function. Something like

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& fout, Array& ary)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ary.theSz; ++i)
    {
        fout << ary.theAry[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

As written `Array<Items>&` declares a reference to an `Items` specialization of the `Array` class, but your class is not a template, so you cannot pass a template argument.

If your `Array` class **is supposed to be a template**, you should declare it as such

```
template <class Items>
class Array
{
  friend ostream& operator << (ostream& fout, Array& ary);
  private:
  int theSz;
  int totSz;
  Items *theAry;
};
```

Comment: I got the impression that the class was indeed templated, but the template part was just not included in the OP (hence the need for an MCVE).

Comment: I guess `Array` is a template after all, but the OP failed to provide the required information.

Comment: Can (and hence should) you not omit the `<Items>` inside the definition of `Array<Items>`, as there `Array` automatically refers to `Array<Items>`?

Comment: @Walter Oops you are correct! Edited to fix that.

Comment: @CoeyKramer : i cant' eliminate the Array<items> because in Array.cc all the implmentation is based on the <items> for example 'template <class Items>
void Array<Items>::Realloc (int newlen)
{
   totSz = Util<Items>::Realloc (newlen, sizeof(Items), theAry);
}

Comment: @Walter: you are right he miss the Array<Items> and so this doesn't help